# When I read in a variable why does matlab return this?

Tags: excel, matlab, xls

I have an excel data set that has one column which is a list of files paths that I would like to read into Matlab.  When I use the `xlsread` command I obtain the following result

```
raw = 

'files'        
[1x135 char]  
[1x135 char] 
[1x141 char] 
[1x141 char] 
[1x149 char]
[1x149 char]
```

Now I understand that the file path in element 1 was 135 characters, but what I don't understand is how to get Matlab to display the path.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html).  As the [xlsread documentation states](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#outputarg_raw), the `raw` output argument is cell array.  Cell array elements are accessed as follows:

```
myPath = raw{2}
```

Note the curly braces rather than normal brackets.  When displaying cell array contents, MATLAB will only display the content of a matrix if is below a certain size, which is why all your paths are not showing in this format.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I see you are new around here, so perhaps you could accept my answer as correct by clicking the big green tick :)

Comment: I was going to, but they only allow me to do functional things after a certain amount of time.  When the time restriction is up I definitely will. :)